# WCF service proxy times out on Close

Tags: wcf, .net-3.5, timeout

I have a WCF client app that creates a new proxy instance for each call. I call Close() on the previous instance to ensure that the connection is closed, but it always times out after 1 minutes, which is the default close time. I previously called Abort() in this case, and not Close(), but then I realized I would exceed my default limit of 10 concurrent connections. I'm not sure what's causing the Close() call to time out. Looking at the WCF trace logs I see a section of logs showing the following, but it's not clear to me if it's a result of me calling Close() or something automatically doing this:

- A Message was closed
- A Message was closed
- A Message was closed again

My service has the following behavior defined:

```
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true, AutomaticSessionShutdown = false, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
```

Below is my service behavior:

```
  <service behaviorConfiguration="AdminServiceBehavior" name="My.WebServices.AdminService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="AdminUserNameBinding"
      name="wsHttpBindingWithAuthAdmin" contract="My.WebServices.IAdminService">
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mexAdminBinding"
      contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

What do I need to do to gracefully Close() my connection without timing out? I've read articles on when to call Close() vs. Abort(), and if you should Dispose / use a 'using' block, but the fact that Close() times out on me and Abort() doesn't free up a concurrent session baffles me.

This may have to do with [AutomataticSessionShutdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.automaticsessionshutdown.aspx), but I'm not sure why it would cause Close() to abort. To be honest, I do not know why I have that property set to false.

**Update**: Setting AutomaticSessionShutdown to true (default value) allows me to call Close() without timing out. This seems to work, but I'm not sure why.